# vscode devcontainer "postCreateCommand": "alias 'll=ls -alF'"

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I am using a default MS configuration (in Visual Studio Code -> "Remote-Container: Add Development Container Configuration Files...") and added the following to the

`.devcontainer/devcontainer.json`

```
"postCreateCommand": "alias ll='ls -alF'"
```

Using the command manually in the vscode terminal after creation yields the desired `ll`.

**How do I have to specify the `"postCreateCommand"`-entry to get the alias?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong. You want to have the `ll` alias available inside the container.
You can achieve this by:

1. Adding this to the Dockerfile:  
   `RUN echo "alias ll='ls -alF'" >> /etc/bash.bashrc`

**If you want to leave the Dockerfile as is:**

2. Use the postCreateCommand from vscode (If you don't want to change the dockerfile):
   `"postCreateCommand": "echo alias ll=\\'ls -alF\\' >> /etc/bash.bashrc"`
   This will add the alias directly to the **system-wide** bashrc file. The alias will be available in all interactive shells started within the container.

   **OR**

   `"postCreateCommand": "echo alias ll=\\'ls -alF\\' >> ~/.bash_aliases"`
   This adds the alias to a separate file specifically for aliases and **doesn't require root access** in the container. **Be aware:** You'll need to source the .bash_aliases in .bashrc or else this won't work.(credit: [@user317808](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62741303/vscode-devcontainer-postcreatecommand-alias-ll-ls-alf#comment134985072_62981271))

If you run into a "Permission denied" then you can also do this:
`"postCreateCommand": "echo alias ll=\\'ls -alF\\' >> /home/vscode/.bashrc"` (credit: [@Damian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62741303/vscode-devcontainer-postcreatecommand-alias-ll-ls-alf#comment134903569_62981271))

Comment: I tested the `postCreateCommand` - works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: I get an error ```/bin/sh: 1: cannot create /etc/bash.bashrc: Permission denied```

Comment: But this works:
```"postCreateCommand": "echo alias ll=\\'ls -alF\\' >> /home/vscode/.bashrc",```

Comment: In case it helps anyone, to avoid needing root permission, I used ~/.bash_aliases to accomplish this.

Comment: Would there be a way to have an expanding version of this? This means wanting to set a series of alias or bash functions that the team could use but not at the point of messing with the dockerfile. Sort of creating like a `.bashrc` that can get passed in the postCreateCommand

Comment: The solution from @user317808 should be the answer