# Can I specify user-specific config for Visual Studio Code devcontainers?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, vscode-devcontainer

My team are using [Visual Studio Code devcontainers](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/containers) in a repo that we all use. devcontainers is a great way to provide a consistent development environment however there are still nuanced differences that different team members want to make when using devcontainers. In my case I would like to install some utilities (e.g. [rich](https://github.com/Textualize/rich), [jless](https://jless.io/)) but I don't want to bloat the container image for everyone (in fact I raised a PR to add one of these tools to the container image Dockerfile and it got rejected). Similarly I'd like to create some aliases that I commonly use and I know I can do so by [using postCreateCommand in devcontainer.json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62981271/201657) however, again, I don't want to bloat devcontainer.json with stuff that only I use.

I've read the documentation on devcontainers, specifically on devcontainer.json, and I couldn't find a way of making changes to the container that only affect the container for myself.

Does anyone know a way that I can install tools and create aliases in the container that will only be done for myself? Speaking more generally, is there a way to make changes to the devcontainer that only apply to me, not anyone else?

Comment: No reply here so I've raised this as a feature request https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/180399

Comment: There's a reply on that issue that suggests Personalizing with dotfiles could help: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/containers#_personalizing-with-dotfile-repositories . Haven't checked it out yet but from what I read there it definitely looks promising.

Comment: dotfiles definitely did the job. Check it out.